# How to validate whether all csv files have the same first line?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, awk

I have a directory containing many csv files. I want a shell script to check whether the first line of each file is the same. For example, these files have the same header, so the check should return True.

```
❯ cat file1.csv
column1,column2,column3
3,1,3
4,3,9
❯ cat file2.csv
column1,column2,column3
5,4,1
1,8,2
```

I thought this would be an already asked question, but I haven't seen it on Stackoverflow.

This question is similar, which checks whether all lines in one file are the same: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/533915/check-if-all-lines-in-a-file-are-same.

What I've tried:

- `echo "$(ls -AU | head -1)"` gets me the first line of one file
- I thought about trying to assert that all files have this value as a first line (preferably as a concise pipe rather than `for` loop), but couldn't figure out how to do this
- I've tried to use the answer here https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/533917, which uses `uniq` and `wc`, but both commands seem specific to iterating through lines of a single file (rather than iterating over a generic list output)

Comment: please update the question with your coding attempts as well as the (wrong) output generated by your code

Comment: What if there's more than one kind of header present in several files, which would you deem canonical? I'd suggest using e.g. `awk` or `sed` to print all csv files' first lines, `sort` & `uniq -c` them, then decide which one to grep for.

Comment: are all files guaranteed to have at least 1 line?

Comment: @markp-fuso - thanks for the comments - I added a "what I've tried" section. The files should have at least one line

Comment: @tink - I'm trying to validate that all files have the exact same first line. So if some file has a different header, the function should return False. `uniq` sounds like a reasonable idea, but from googling, it seems like that checks lines of a file, rather than comparing across many files

Comment: And if the first file you pick is the outlier? And re-read my comment. I said: output the first line of each file. Check those. Minus outputting all different headers cyrus' solution is close to my suggestion.

Comment: When you say "return" - shell scripts don't "return" anything, they print output and they exit with a status, so do you mean you want your script to print the strings "true"/"false" or you want it to exit with a status meaning success/fail or both or something else?

Comment: @EdMorton - thanks for the clarification about "return"ing! At least for my purposes, it doesn't matter as long as there's different output printed for the two cases (1/0, "true"/"false", or even just the raw count of unique headers like in the first line from Cyrus's response)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With GNU `sed` and `bash`:

```
rows=$(sed -s '1!d' *.csv | sort -u | wc -l)
if [[ "$rows" -eq 1 ]]; then echo "true"; else echo "false"; fi
```

`sed -s '1!d' *.csv` outputs to stdout first line of all files in current directory with suffix `.csv`.

Comment: I was thinking `head -q -n 1 *.csv | sort -u | wc -l`, but uncertain as to which would scale better with more files

Comment: From my point of view your `head` command does the same as my `sed` command.

Comment: Thanks! This works! It seems to also work if I replace `sort -u` with `uniq`

Comment: @j_b - your answer here also looks nice and concise. As a complete aside, I tried on a mac. The -q option doesn't work on mac's `head`. I almost got it to work with the following, but there seems to be a newline included in the count that I can't get rid of (so it counts one more than it should) `head -n 1 *.csv | grep '==>' | sort -u | wc -l`

Comment: @maurera I was testing on ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS using `head` (GNU coreutils) 8.32

Comment: `grep -hm1 . *.csv | sort -u | wc -l` with GNU `grep` maybe.

Comment: @Jetchisel - I've confirmed that works on a mac

Answer (score 4):

One `awk` idea:

```
awk '
    { headers[$0]; nextfile }             # use 1st line as array index; skip to next file
END { if ( length(headers)==1 )           # if array only has one entry then ...
         print "true"                     # all files have the same header line
      else                                # else ...
         print "false"                    # there is more than one unique header
    }
' *.csv
```

Comment: You should mention that requires an awk version that supports both `nextfile` and `length(array)` such as GNU awk. Neither of those functionalities are in POSIX yet.

Answer (score 2):

It is helpful to know WHICH file is different.

Given:

```
head -n 2 *.csv
==> file1.csv <==
column1,column2,column3
3,1,3

==> file2.csv <==
column1,column2,column3
5,4,1

==> file3.csv <==
column_diff,column2,column3
5,4,1

==> file4.csv <==
column1,column2,column3
5,4,1
```

You can use this Ruby to determine the offender:

```
ruby -e 'keys=ARGV.each_with_object(Hash.new {|h,k| h[k] = []}){|fn,h| 
    h[File.open(fn).readline.chomp]<<fn
}
keys.each{|k,v| puts "#{k}\n\t#{v.join("\n\t")}"}
' *.csv
```

Prints:

```
column1,column2,column3
    file1.csv
    file2.csv
    file4.csv
column_diff,column2,column3
    file3.csv
```

If you want to be able to test from Bash the result:

```
ruby -e 'keys=ARGV.each_with_object(Hash.new {|h,k| h[k] = []}){|fn,h| 
    h[File.open(fn).readline.chomp]<<fn
}
if keys.length>1 then
    keys.each{|k,v| puts "#{k}\n\t#{v.join("\n\t")}"}
    exit(false)
else
    puts "All files equal"
end
' *.csv
```

Then just test the exit code.

Answer (score 1):

Using GNU `head` (for the `-q` option), this one-liner should do the trick:

```
if [ -z "$(head -q -n1 *.csv | uniq -u)" ]; then echo true; else echo false; fi
```

The `-q` option of GNU `head` will suppress printing of filenames. `uniq -u` will give no output only if all lines are the same. `sort` isn't necessary for this task.

Answer (score 0):

Using any awk (untested):

```
awk '
    FNR == 1 {
        if ( $0 != prev ) {
            status = 1
            exit
        }
        prev = $0
        nextfile
    }
    END {
        print ( status ? "false" : "true" )
        exit status
    }
' *.csv
```

It'll run faster if your awk supports `nextfile` but it'll work either way.

I'm assuming above that you want your script both print "true"/"false" and to exit with a success/fail status.